# subset by diel period over multiple days (subset by multiple columns from a different df)

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to subset telemetry data into diel periods. The telemetry data spans 7 months, and I would like the subsets to use daily sunrise data.

Let's say `df1` is my telemetry data, and `df2` is my sunrise data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-01 04:30", "2016-05-01 07:00", "2016-05-01 13:50", 
                   "2016-05-03 03:50", "2016-05-04 18:20", "2016-05-06-04:20")),
  ID = c("A1", "B3", "A2", "A2", "B1", "B2")
)


df2 <- data.frame(
  date = as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-01", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-06")),
  ntwilight.start = c("03:25:00", "03:23:00", "03:21:00", "03:19:00", "03:17:00", "03:15:00"),
  sunrise = c("04:45:00", "04:44:00", "04:42:00", "04:40:00", "04:39:00", "04:37:00")
)
df2$ntwilight.start <- as.POSIXct(paste(df2$date, df2$ntwilight.start, sep = " "), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
df2$sunrise <- as.POSIXct(paste(df2$date, df2$sunrise, sep = " "), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

In order to create a subset for dawn, I need to select all rows from `df1` where `datetime` falls between `ntwilight.start` and `sunrise` from `df2`. The subset should then look like:

```
             datetime ID
1 2016-05-01 04:30:00 A1
2 2016-05-03 03:50:00 A2
3 2016-05-06 04:20:00 B2
```

I am able to subset `df1` using a single pair of time values

```
dawn <- df1[df1$datetime >= as.POSIXct("2016-05-01 03:25", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") & df1$datetime < as.POSIXct("2016-05-01 04:45", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]
```

However, the following code fails to provide the proper matches:

```
dawn2 <- df1[df1$datetime >= df2$ntwilight.start & df1$datetime < df2$sunset,]
```

**How would I go about having `R` search `df2` for the row with a matching date, and use the appropriate row in `df2` to determine the subset?**

I feel as though I likely need to separate the date and time into different columns (for both data frames), and possibly need to group `df1` by date, and subset each group separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used some `dplyr` magic to join your dataframes by date and then I filtered the resulting dataframe by

```
df1 <- data.frame(
datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-01 04:30", "2016-05-01 07:00", "2016-05-01 13:50", 
                        "2016-05-03 03:50", "2016-05-04 18:20", "2016-05-06 04:20"),
                      , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
ID = c("A1", "B3", "A2", "A2", "B1", "B2")
)

df1$date <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df1$datetime), format = "%Y-%m-%d") #there is probably a better way to isolate date, but this works...


df2 <- data.frame(
date = as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-01", "2016-05-02", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-04", "2016-05-05", "2016-05-06")),
ntwilight.start = c("03:25:00", "03:23:00", "03:21:00", "03:19:00", "03:17:00", "03:15:00"),
sunrise = c("04:45:00", "04:44:00", "04:42:00", "04:40:00", "04:39:00", "04:37:00")
)

df2$ntwilight.start <- as.POSIXct(paste(df2$date, df2$ntwilight.start, sep = " "), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
df2$sunrise <- as.POSIXct(paste(df2$date, df2$sunrise, sep = " "), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")



library(dplyr)
dawn2 <- df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2,by = "date") %>%                            # join the 2 data frames by date
    filter(datetime >= ntwilight.start, datetime < sunrise)   # filter datetime before twilight and after sunrise
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.